# Android Retrofit - Models are GSON arrays from API

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

When receiving data from an open weather API I am receiving nulls. I am using retroFit2 within android to get the data. Here is the message from the log:

```
 onResponse: server response Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, 
 onResponse: WeatherResponse{weather=com.weatherapp.models.Weather@197d237}
```

Here is the GSON:

```
 {
"coord": {
    "lon": -5.93,
    "lat": 54.58
},
"weather": [
    {
        "id": 804,
        "main": "Clouds",
        "description": "overcast clouds",
        "icon": "04d"
    }
],
"base": "stations",
"main": {
    "temp": 293.15,
    "feels_like": 288.01,
    "temp_min": 293.15,
    "temp_max": 293.15,
    "pressure": 1024,
    "humidity": 37
},
"visibility": 10000,
"wind": {
    "speed": 5.7,
    "deg": 160
},
"clouds": {
    "all": 96
},
"dt": 1590770221,
"sys": {
    "type": 1,
    "id": 1376,
    "country": "GB",
    "sunrise": 1590724667,
    "sunset": 1590785095
},
```

MODEL

```
@SerializedName("coord")
@Expose
private CoOrdinateModel coOrdinateModel;

@SerializedName("weather")
@Expose
private WeatherModel[] weatherModel;

@SerializedName("main")
@Expose
private MainModel main;

@SerializedName("visibility")
@Expose
private String visibility;

@SerializedName("wind")
@Expose
private WindModel wind;
```

RESPONSE

```
 public class WeatherResponse {

@SerializedName("coord")
@Expose()
private Weather weather;

public Weather getWeather() {
    return weather;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "WeatherResponse{" +
            "weather=" + weather +
            '}';
}
}
```

API

```
  @GET("/data/2.5/weather")
Call<WeatherResponse> getWeather(
        @Query("id") String ID,
        @Query("APPID") String API_KEY
);
```

I ideally need almost all the data from the GSON to parse through into java objects within the android app. I've done this before with simpler GSON, but this one has arrays inside and I'm not sure if my MODEL class is done correctly to accommodate this.

Any help in identifying the root cause of the nulls would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response model is incorrect -

```
@SerializedName("main")
@Expose
private float main[];
```

it should be -

```
@SerializedName("main")
@Expose
private MainModel main;
```

and your `MainModel` would be the POJO class which you are trying to parse -

```
public class MainModel {
   @SerializedName("temp")
   public Double temp;
   @SerializedName("feels_like")
   public Double feelsLike;
}
```

Refer same for others as well like `wind` as they can't be parsed with String class.

Comment: I updated my question with your updated approach to the Modelling, could you take a look at it please. The response from the server is no longer returning nulls its returning: onResponse: WeatherResponse{weather=com.weatherapp.models.Weather@197d237}

Comment: So what's left now you are already sorted? You just need getter `public Weather getWeather() {return main;}` in your main model class where you added `private MainModel main;` and you can access all the things which are there in the `Weather` class

Comment: Im not sure I thought the response in the log should show the data being parse, its only showing WeatherResponse{weather=com.weatherapp.models.Weather@197d237 so I don't know if its working properly

Comment: Nah its not working when I call the response.body().getWeather().getMain().getTemp()  It crashes the app due to a null, so the values arent parsing :(

Comment: Logcat cant print the items inside the class object `WeatherResponse{weather=com.weatherapp.models.Weather@197d237` that's the reason its showing like this. I guess your issue is something else now.

Comment: that's awesome! :)

Answer (score 1):

Those "arrays" you're talking about aren't arrays, they're nested objects (well, `weather` is an array of objects, but still). In order to handle this, you need to create nested classes on your model class to handle the nested object types, like so:

```
public class Weather {
    public class Coordinate {
        @SerializedName("lat")
        @Expose
        public float lat;

        @SerializedName("long")
        @Expose
        public float long;
    }

    // ...

    @SerializedName("coord")
    @Expose
    public Coordinate coOrd;

    // repeat for every nested object type
}
```

For the `weather` key specifically, remember that that is an *array* of objects, and as such the field on your model should be declared as:

```
public WeatherData[] weather; // or whatever you name the nested class as
                              // I wouldn't recommend Weather, since you've
                              // already named your model that
```

Comment: How do I add a constructor and getters and setters to a class which has a bunch of other classes nested in it, Or do I have to create a Model class for each nested block individually?

Comment: You'd just add them as normal; nested classes shouldn't affect your ability to add cobstructors and other methods to my knowledge.

Comment: Mate I updated the MODEL part of the question to show my new model. The response isnt returning nulls anymore its returning: onResponse: WeatherResponse{weather=com.weatherapp.models.Weather@197d237}